# Squarespace Announcement Bar cut off on Android Chrome Browser

Tags: android, css, google-chrome, squarespace

I'm working on a Squarespace website (I can't post the link because of privacy reasons). I'm adding an announcement bar to the site, for covid info. It works fine almost everywhere, except on chrome in android. On that browser, when the page is first loaded, the very top of the text is cut off. Here's an image:
[Image of bar cut off](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nlGP1.jpg). (sorry it isn't a screenshot my phone won't take screenshots in incognito and it was in incognito for unrelated reasons).

Chrome won't allow me to scroll up anymore, which would correct the issue. When I reload the page, it starts off looking the same. However, I now I *do* have the ability to scroll up.

I've attempted a couple of solutions. Firstly, I've tried to set the z index of the bar higher. But that didn't help. I've also tried to add a script which automatically scrolls the user to the top using `window.scrollTo(0, 0);` but that also failed.

Sorry I can't show code, it's a Squarespace site. I hope someone can help. Thanks.

Edit: I've done some checking and it happens on computer chrome too when I make the screen small enough, but NOT when I switch "devices" in inspect element. However, the problem isn't there on iphone. Chrome on iphone uses webkit, while on other devices it uses Blink, so I think Blink may be the source of the issue

Comment: If you suspect that this could be related to your own custom CSS or JavaScript, try removing portions of it, saving, and reloading on your device until you find the issue. Otherwise, for the sake of troubleshooting, I'd suggest creating another site from the same template as the site in question, enable the announcement bar, and see if it responds the same. If not, then it's a question of what is unique on the site in question. If so, you can then post a link to the demo site for others to diagnose.

Comment: I can't add my own site, as I don't own the squarespace account sadly.

Comment: Anyone can start a Squarespace site. All you need is an email address. At that point, it's a matter of choosing the same template as the site in question.

Comment: You can't add an announcement bar without premium.

Comment: While in trial mode (up to 14 days, but can be extended), you can use the site as if it had premium features.